# Empty Jacoco test report in android

Tags: android, code-coverage, robolectric, jacoco

I have tried to generate test report in android, I am getting empty test report always.I have tried all the solution did not work yet. Could you please help me out.

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

android {

 testOptions {
    unitTests.all {
        setIgnoreFailures(true)
    }
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        testCoverageEnabled true
        }
    }
} 

task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: 'testInternalDebugUnitTest') {
    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }

    def fileFilter = ['**/R.class', '**/R$*.class', '**/BuildConfig.*', '**/Manifest*.*', '**/*Test*.*', 'android/**/*.*']
    def debugTree = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/intermediates/classes/debug", excludes: fileFilter)
    def mainSrc = "${project.projectDir}/src/main/java"

    sourceDirectories = files([mainSrc])
    classDirectories = files([debugTree])
    //executionData = files("${buildDir}/jacoco/testInternalDebugUnitTest.exec")
    executionData = fileTree(dir: "$buildDir", includes: ["jacoco/testInternalDebugUnitTest.exec","outputs/code-coverage/connected/flavors/internalDebug/coverage.ec"])
}
```

I am getting log.

```
Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Timer-54"

Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Timer-62"

Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Timer-65"
```

is there any thing incorrect?
[image]

Comment: I think I am facing a similar issue. Have you managed to find a solution?